# How to configure redirect_uri on azure ad to respond to two different environments?

Tags: django, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-graph-api

I have the integration just working perfectly, however a small problem arose, I have two different domains with their own instances, the app.company.com environment and the jobs.compamy.com environment, in the app and jobs code I configured the redirect uri in order to always be answered for your domain, and configured in the app ad the two different urls, however the routing is not done correctly the app always redirects to the first reply url which causes me an error of the type: I log in via app environment but I'm redirected to the jobs environment.

This code in Environments, redirect uri is a environment variable:

```py
aad_auth = OAuth2Session(
        company_azure['app_id'],
        scope='User.Read email openid profile',
        redirect_uri=settings.AD_REDIRECT_URI
    )
```

This Redirect uris on my app:

```py
https://jobs.company.com/login_azure_ad/callback
https://app.company.com/login_azure_ad/callback
```

Comment: It seems that you can configure redirect_uri='https://jobs.company.com/login_azure_ad/callback' and redirect_uri='https://app.company.com/login_azure_ad/callback' separately.

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea, not through environmental variables, but directly to the URL.

```
//in jobs code
    aad_auth = OAuth2Session(
            company_azure['app_id'],
            scope='User.Read email openid profile',
            redirect_uri='https://jobs.company.com/login_azure_ad/callback'
        )
//in app code
    aad_auth = OAuth2Session(
            company_azure['app_id'],
            scope='User.Read email openid profile',
            redirect_uri='https://app.company.com/login_azure_ad/callback'
        )
```